# Backstage - Changing Page Header Color

Tags: material-ui, backstage

I am trying to change the *header* text color on pages in Backstage (Spotify's open source software catalog).  I have tried using themes as advised in Backstage documentation, but there is no way to specifically override the header text color (I can change the background colour, but not the color of the text.

I have tried a few solutions - this changes the background color of the header to white but the text remains white (default color) and actual header text cannot be read (white text on white background):

```
genPageTheme({colors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff'], shape: shapes.wave})
```

I then found the ability to add a fontColor to the genPageTheme function and tried the following, but again it did not change the header color - I am not sure if I am calling it incorrectly:

```
genPageTheme({colors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff'], shape: shapes.wave, options: {fontColor: '#B1D8FF'} }),
```

I also took a look at customizing the overall theme but found there is no field that allows the header to be modified (neither background nor text):

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    ...lightTheme.palette,
    primary: {
      main: '#2670A9',
    },
    :
    :
```

I figure there is a way to do this using material-ui (MUI) directly since Backstage uses MUI but I would like to stay true to the Backstage customization approach of using their themes.

Any ideas how the header text color can be changed?  Any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [BackstageOverrides](https://backstage.io/docs/getting-started/app-custom-theme/#overriding-backstage-and-material-ui-components-styles). This will allow you to override default Backstage settings.

This will allow you to customize (a lot) your application.

A simple example:

```js
import { BackstageOverrides } from '@backstage/core-components';
import { BackstageTheme } from '@backstage/theme';

export const customThemeOverrides = (
  theme: BackstageTheme,
): BackstageOverrides => {
  return {
    BackstagePage: {
      root: {
        display: 'grid',
        overflow: 'hidden !important',
        gridTemplateColums: '30px 280px 3fr 30px',
        gridTemplateAreas:
          '"header header header header" ". sidenav content ." ". sidenav content . "',
      },
    },

    BackstageHeader: {
      header: {
        height: '80px',
        gridArea: 'header',
        display: 'flex',
        borderBottom: `1px solid #FFFFFF`,
        backgroundImage: `none`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        padding: '50px',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        background: `#FFFFFF`
      },
      rigthItemsBox: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      title: {
        color: `#FFFFFF`,
        fontSize: 24,
      },
      subtitle: {
        color: `#666666`,
      },
      type: {
        color: `#FFFFFF`,
      },
    },
    BackstageHeaderLabel: {
      label: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      root: { color: '#FFFFFF',  },
      value: { color: '#FFFFFF' },
    },

  };
};
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that (I saw your response on another question and on the Backstage site - great work!)... unfortunately, the header contains artifacts on the far right of the page (mostly "owner" and "lifecycle" but sometimes other stuff) which do *not* have their text change colours.  So, what I get is a header colour change, main text has suitable contrast, but the "owner" and "lifecycle" are not changed... Any ideas on how to extend the font text colour to owner/lifecycle?

Comment: Thanks for the compliments man!

Well, as for what you want to do is in this same file that I mentioned, you will basically act on:

- BackstageHeader.rightItemsBox.color
- BackstageHeader.type.color
- BackstageHeaderLabel.label.color
- BackstageHeaderLabel.root.color
- BackstageHeaderLabel.value.color

An sample example:
```ts

[...]

BackstageHeaderLabel: {
      label: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      root: { color: '#FFFFFF',  },
      value: { color: '#FFFFFF' },
    },

[...]
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion and now the header and right parts work properly, but the navigation colours remain black (default, I guess) and do not change when I use "creaetTheme" palette.navigation ... no matter what I change (background, indicator, color, selectedC olor etc) the navigation color control is lost... any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the backstage lightTheme.navigation.background is taking precedence over the custom theme overrides?  (not sure how that happens)

Comment: @PauloEduardo I seems that the link in the answer is not pointing to the correct location. Maybe you wanted to refer to [this link](https://backstage.io/docs/getting-started/app-custom-theme#overriding-backstage-and-material-ui-components-styles)?

Comment: Exactly!
I will correct the reference.